# Getting partial value of a field

Tags: jasper-reports

How can I grab partial value of field in *iReport*? for example I got a field

- Field A contains = "This is a test script, please ignore"
- I would like to remove "This is a test script, " and just display "please ignore" in my report

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the standard string operations upon the field in the expression, like substring, charAt etc. to obtain the string of your requirement in the field.

For instance :

```
$F{myDatafield}.substring(10)
```

or

```
$F{myDatafield}.substring(0,10)  etc.
```

Whatever suits your cause.

Comment: how can I do this with a regex in the substring? for example ("display "(.*?)") because the front part is not static but the "display" word is static and stop at the last "

Comment: NVM because stack overflow is so damm helpful, I found a way what I did was $F{myDatafield}.substring($F{myDatafield}.indexOf("display "")+10,$F{myDatafield}.lastIndexOf("""))